# PhoneGap build - gap:platform not excluding files from each platform build

Tags: phonegap-build

Per the documentation:
Warning:

If you do not supply the gap:platform attribute, the referenced image will be copied to ALL platforms, increasing the size of their application packages.

I have icons and splash screens that reference each iOS and Android, for example:

```
<icon src="res/icon/android/icon-xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
```

Why is it when I upload my zip to PhoneGap Build, the resulting IPA and APK include these files for both platforms?  I was hoping the gap:platform would NOT include the files in the resulting platform build.  I have been trying to use the .pgbomit file without any luck, so far.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying. Are you saying that you are getting the icon for multiple platforms in one package?  For instance, if you download the ipa (the iOS version of your App), you are getting the icons for Android. If so, how can you tell this is happening? If not, what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using the .pgbomit file.